# I'm trying to update DOM with Sorted Numbers using css height bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm creating Height bars with 40 Random valus(like Sorting visualizer). and i'm using mergesort for sorting so at the time of updating DOM first time i'm creating random values 1 by 1 in loop while updating it in DOM with CSS height...

But in this case i already have 40 Sorted Numbers in list so how can i update DOM for each index to print values in DOM using css height (see the below [RadomNumberGeneratedImage][1] to understand what i'm trying to do)... **bcz in random number i'm creating it 1 by 1 but now i already have 40 values in list so i can't figure it out how to implement it for each index values..** whenever i click mergeSort button the DOM gets clear using .empty but then it's not showing anything or it will just shows the last Sorted value for all 40 bars (Ex: 190 190 190.....) instead of Sorted bars.. how can i show for each index and stop after once it Sorted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `i` does not increment & stays at his last position in your code above, it will always set last value of `Sorted` as height for all bars,

Instead what we can do it, reset `i` to `0` before starting forEach & increment once for all iterations

Just make sure that `.frequencyItem` elements length is same as `Sorted` array length

```
i = 0;
$('.frequencyItem').each(function()
{
   x = Sorted[i++];
   $(this).css("height", x);
});
```

Comment: I have one more doubt... I want to slow it down the mergesort algorithm in real time using like Auxiliary array... Like i want to show the 2 value which mergesort is comaparing and colour them red and after swapping or after overriding those values back to the normal colour... Any idea how can i do that?

Comment: You'll need to write your code that updates css heights of the element inside the mergeSort function, then write css to delay height change & color change of element to show animated effect, then delay your mergeSort function using setTimeout function